# Cassandra - Unable to locate MemTable variables in cassandra.yaml

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

The maximum write performance of my 3 node cassandra cluster is 17K operations per seconds. How do i increase this ? Lots of articles have suggested me to modify the values of MemTable variables (like flushes_after_mins, throughput_in_mb and operations_in_millions) but I am unable to find those in the cassandra.yaml file. I am using cassandra version 2.1.2

Answer (score 2):

You might be reading some old documentation.  For instance, the 2.1 doc on [The cassandra.yaml configuration file](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html) indicates the following replacements for two of the fields you mentioned:

- `memtable_throughput_in_mb` was replaced by `memtable_total_space_in_mb`.
- `memtable_operations_in_millions` was replaced by `memtable_total_space_in_mb`.

For the complete list of properties you can set, scroll down to the section titled "Memtable settings."

Note that I couldn't find for your "flushes_after_mins" setting.  But if you read through the section I mentioned above, perhaps you could get the desired level of tuning by setting either `memtable_flush_queue_size`, `memtable_flush_writers`, or `memtable_cleanup_threshold`.  Note that changes to these (or the settings mentioned above) need to be made on all of your nodes, which also need to be restarted to take effect.

Comment: Not able to find "memtable_total_space_in_mb" as well, i can see "memtable_heap_space_in_mb" and "memtable_offheap_space_in_mb". Are these the same ?? Any problem if I add "memtable_total_space_in_mb"  to the file ??

Comment: @user3775565 That should be a problem.  I know that I've added properties to the yaml file before.